# Get certain substring from a string value

Tags: java, android, substring

I have the following dates:

```
"Friday, January 31",
"Wednesday, February 12",
"Monday, February 17",
"Wednesday, March 5",
```

I want to set up a string function where I am given the number always:

```
31
12
17
5
```

I started with this function:

```
String strCheck = suspendedDates[i];
int pos = strCheck.length();
int pos2 = strCheck.indexOf(" ");
```

I am stuck right now, because how does it know which `" "` is it?

Can someone help me with the function.

Comment: It will take the first, as the documentation states. _"Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative of @JigarJoshi answer you can use a regex if you don't mind, removing all non-number characters.

```
String result = dateString.replaceAll("[^\\d]+","");
```

Comment: Too much code + a regex is a heavy thing. If he only needs to get the last number and the format is the same he should use: Too much code. Just use s.substring(c.lastIndexOf(" "), s.length())

Comment: @DanielNuriyev I don't know if the format is always the same, but for the other thing you are right that is why i start my answer with  "as an alternative" ;) im not gonna copy paste what other already answer

Answer (score 4):

use [`lastIndexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String%29) instead of `indexOf()`

```
final String str = "Friday, January 31";
System.out.println(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(" ")));
```

- [Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/tXSxwR)

Answer (score 2):

Get the substring from the end.  Instead of trying to figure out locations

```
strCheck.substring(strCheck.length()-2);
```

This will take the last two characters.  Then just do a `trim()` in case it's a single character to remove the space:-

```
strCheck.substring(strCheck.length()-2).trim();
```

**Alternative**

The other option as mentioned is to do a `lastIndexOf()` on the `String` with a space (" ") as an argument which will search backward from the end of the `String` till it finds the space.  But as the number can always be extracted in 2 character spaces, I see no reason to do 2 character compares every time you want to extract a known size `String` (2) in a known location (`length()-2`) in order to retrieve the location that you already know.

Comment: There is no need to modify a string if he only needs to look up the last number. If the format is constant just do: Too much code. Just use s.substring(c.lastIndexOf(" "), s.length())

Comment: My code goes to the index given and extracts the desired `String`, yours will search backward from the end of the `String` doing compares until it finds a " ".   Without the optional `trim()` my code is actually more efficient.

Comment: Look at the amount of code inside trim, including unnecessary code in this case. But it is quite possible that the difference is not significant. Let's run it a million times.

Answer (score 2):

I had to post it; since this is a date I would go with Date parse to allow an additional check on the format of the inputs:

An alternative way:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM DD");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(format.parse("Friday, January 31"));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("DD").format(cal.getTime()));
```

2nd `SimpleDateFormat("DD")` is used instead of deprecated `getDate()`.

Comment: +1 if the format is always the same this is more oop solution using SimpleFormatDate,

Comment: @nachokk thanks, and yes I could, there's always a scope I guess :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to divide the string into parts for parsing, i suggest using String.split(" "), look at the javadocs and the internet for lots of nice examples of this in use! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
 String str = "Friday, January 31";
 Scanner s = new Scanner(s);
 s.useDelimiter( "\\D+" );
 while ( s.hasNextInt() ){
   s.nextInt(); // get int
 }
```

Comment: Too much code. Just use s.substring(c.lastIndexOf(" "), s.length())

Comment: but more effective if you later want to extract more information or the format changes.